# $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ diagonal matrix with charac. polynomial $(x-a)^p(x-b)^q$ , what is the dimension of the space of matrices commuting with $A$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n \times n $ diagonal matrix with real entries with characteristic polynomial $(x-a)^p(x-b)^q$ , where $a,b$ are distinct real numbers ; let $V:=\{B \in M(n,\mathbb R):AB=BA\}$  then $V$ is a subspace of $M(n,\mathbb R)$ , what is the dimension of $V$ ?

Comment: Perhaps include your work on the problem so far?

Comment: Otherwise you might explain where the problem was found or what makes it interesting to you?

Answer (score 2):

The subspace you seek is the Lie algebra of the centralizer of your diagonal matrix in $GL(n)$, and has dimension $p^2 + q^2$.

Proof: Consider a matrix $B$ which commutes with diagonal matrix under consideration. Write $\mathbb R^n = V_a  \oplus V_b$, where $V_a$ is the eigenspace for $a$ and $V_b$ likewise for $b$. Then for $v \in V_a$, we have $A(Bv) = B(Av) = a(Bv)$. Thus $B$ preserves the subspace $V_a$. The same argument shows it presrves $V_b$, too. Thus $B$ itself can be put in block form which consists of $p^2 + q^2$ entries.